# Default value in WPS input

Tags: geoserver, wps

I'm using GeoServer and want to add a WPS with default values.

How can I define an optional parameter as a WPS input?
I think, that I have to define this parameter with a multiplicity of 0, but how can I use a default value?

Do I have to add something in the ApplicationContext.xml?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define the multiplicity of a custom process' parameter, you can do it through `@DescribeParameter`, setting `min` and `max`:

```
...
public String execute(  
@DescribeParameter(name = "myparam", description = "My param", min = 0, max = 1) Integer myparam) {
...
}
```

Reference: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/wps-services/implement-rendertrans.html

Hope it helps!